# How to resolve a memory error on windows system

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging several sizeable dataframes:

```
 path ='D:/filename.csv'
 dfa=pd.read_csv(path, header=0, delimiter=',',encoding='latin-1', dtype=str) 
 dfa=dfa.rename(columns={"ybvd": "yBvD"})
 df=df.merge( dfa, on=['yBvD'], copy=True, how='left')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.8 GiB for an array with shape (1577604547,) and data type int64
```

I don't quite understand why, especially since it doesn't happen for the same merging process each time (I merge several datasets, the code is representative of what I use each time). At no point does the code use more than 60% of my RAM (256GB total RAM capacity). I also have 800GB in virtual memory left. There is plenty of space on the hard disk I want to write the files to.

I am therefore not quite sure what this error is supposed to indicate to me or how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you try using the argument `low_memory` within `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Try to do that batch by batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.8 GiB for an array with shape (1577604547,) and data type int64
```

This mean you do not have enough free space in RAM.

> At no point does the code use more than 60% of my RAM

`pandas` is saying it does need `11.8 GiB`, please consider not how many % of RAM is used, but how many `GiB` is still free.

> how to resolve it.

If you are unable to secure enough RAM space then you would find way to do your operation without loading data all at once, see [*Scaling to large datasets*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html) for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

and using batching approach:

[image]

Code:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

def part_merge(part):
    return df2.merge(part, on='test')
edf = pd.DataFrame()
nss = 10
step = int(len(df1)/nss)
for i in tqdm(range(nss)):
    temp = df1.iloc[i*step:(i+1)*step]
    edf = edf.append(part_merge(temp))
```